FTP server maxes out at 4Mbit upload speed, despite the internet connection being 50Mbit. Why?

Server ISP connection is 50/50 Mbit fiber (verified with speedtests)

Remote ISP connection is 100/100 Mbit fiber (verified with speedtests).

Only large files are transfered (1GB+)

All ethernet cables, no Wifi anywhere.

The FTP server runs on an Zyxel NSA325 v2 NSA.


When server uploads, I'm maxing out at 4 Mbit (550KB). When downloading I'm maxing at 7,5 Mbit (900KB). Tested on multiple devices/clients with similar results.
Anyone know why it's so slow? I'm not expecting full 50Mbit, but less than a tenth of capactity is obviously not correct at all.
I have tried googling the Zyxel device, but can't find anyone else complaining about slow speeds from it.
Edit: The speeds listed above are between two European countries (large distance).
I now have tested close physical location with SAME ISP and got 10Mbit (1,3MB) and 12Mbit (1,5MB).
Still only 1/5th of capacity...

The Zyxel 325 is extremly underpowered CPU-wise, so it just can't do more. It is from a time, when disks could barely sustain 40Mb/s

@EugenRieck but FTP transfers are not a very CPU intensive operation? Using SMB locally, I achieve near 100Mbit, so disk I/O s definitely not an issue. Even with a very slow CPU I would expect more than 10Mbit?

They are on a 325. The kernel in use has no sendfile() and every single packet is pulled in a CPU loop. This is on a CPU with a RAM bandwidth of less than 100MB/s.
Disclaimer: I ran tens of them for customers until bandwiths grew up a decade ago.

The FTP protocol allows bandwidth limiting on both the client and the server.

The CPU had been my first guess, too. Is it really FTP or maybe FTPS or SFTP? Then the CPU is an even bigger factor. If it really isn't the server's CPU: Analyze the local routing! Are your packets slowed down by a router? Are you wrapping the connection in VPN or IPSec?
